unable to access the css variables
after testing the two links:
How to access the :root's element in ReactJS to edit CSS variables? and Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript I am trying to access my css variables that I have created but I'm unable to access them.
here is a snippet of my variables:
:root {
    --circle-diameter: 500px;
    --circle-radius: 250px;
    --circle-transpose: -250px;
    --branch-length: 100px;
    --icon-size: 20px;
    --terminal-colour: orange;
    --overlay-size: 1500px;

}

from there I try to access this value in a .ts file but the return is empty
const root = document.body;
export const TERMINAL_COLOUR =
    getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue("--terminal-colour");
console.log(TERMINAL_COLOUR)

when looking at the console.log there is nothing and just returns nothing in the console.  I thought this was originally a package issue so I also tried installing
npm install styled-components

but it did nothing (and I don't think it was really relevant)
edit:
When letting the application run on npm start if I comment the code then uncomment it, the orange will appear, but if I refresh the page, the console will do an empty log.

I just tested your code in a SO snippet (consider using that in your post so we can immediately test it) and it does work, so cannot replicate? Mine logs orange? Maybe its a timing issue when your style is applied/loaded after the code is executed? It's hard to say as we don't have any extra info on how your styles are being loaded.

@somethinghere I'm new to react so forgive me if ask stupid questions, wouldn't it just throw an error? if it is not instantiated then getProperty should return an error otherwise the variable exists and therefore has a value no?

@a_confused_student I also ran this in a snippet and got the value orange

No, getPropertValue does not throw an error if you request a value. From the docs: "Return Value: A string containing the value of the property. If not set, returns the empty string."

@somethinghere how can I get info on how the styles are being loaded? and by styles do you mean the css files? here I'm just doing a basic typescript react app. I have tested the variables in other .css files and managed to successfully import them but not to the .ts files

@somethinghere does the .css file need to have a specific name?

I'm not so sure, it depends on the system etc... Just to test this you should try adding an interval around it and seeing if the value changes at any point, if it does your styles were loaded. If they are external CSS files you should keep in mind that they need time to load. How it loads is rather dependent on the framework, and I am not a React dev. The file does not need a specific name, that doesn't matter, it just needs to load and then be applied, if your script runs before that the expected value would be an empty string.

@somethinghere I think I see what you mean about the loading I just managed to get the "orange" to print (I'm running npm run start) and I commented the code I showed and uncommented it and it appeared but then wasn't able to reappear when I refreshed the page the log did not reappear

But I presume that you are just loading some page from the server that is spun up with npm start (a React dev server or something) - the issue isn't exactly in the server here, it's in the fact that the browser needs to load the style before it runs the script. It might not be a good idea to export this variable directly, perhaps it's better to export a function to get the value so you can call it when you need it, most likely when your stuff has loaded. Without more context there isn't much more I can do to help here though...

Uhm maybe I'm a little confused but it sounds like you're running your JS server-side. I'm unsure that the server-side can access computed styles as IMHO that is something that only happens on the client-side.

@tacoshy I had a look and it seems that my issue that the document.body changes in value/type when doing the first run vs the refresh
